# как реализовать интерфейс в javascript как можно более нативно?

Tags: javascript, ооп, интерфейс

в программе создаются объекты
например так:

```
var obj;
obj.a=123;
obj.b='abc';
```

эти объекты передаются в функции:

```
print(obj);
function print(o){
  console.log( o.a +' '+o.b );
}
```

проблема в том, что когда одинаковые объекты создаются и используются в разных местах, очень трудно в ручную следить за свойствами, а в яве это делается автоматически и если что не так выдаётся ошибка.

хотелось бы иметь интерфейса как в яве.
может что-то вроде такого:

```
function Data(){
   this.a=0;
   ths.b='';
}
var obj = new Data();
```

только чтобы проверять на совпадение типа или совпадение списка свойств объекта с типом...

про TypeScript я знаю, и еще есть куча велосипедов/библиотек...
но хотелось бы узнать как это обычно реализуется в JavaScript?
по нормальному?

может в ES5 или ES6?

Comment: А никак. [Duck typing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Поэтому для JS и придуманы эти разношёрстные костыли вроде TypeScript, потому что средствами языка это нормально не реализуется.

Comment: посмотри в сторону [flow](https://flow.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Всегда можно реализовать самому нечто подобное:

```js
Function.prototype.hint = function(...types) {
  let fn = this;
  return function(...args) {
    if (args.length !== types.length) throw new Error('Wrong arg num');
    types.forEach((type, i) => {
      if (!(args[i] instanceof type)) throw new Error('Wrong arg type');
    });
    return fn(...args);
  };
};

//////////////////////

class IFoo {
  constructor(foo){ this.foo = foo;}
  getFoo() {return this.foo;}
}

class A extends IFoo {}
class B {}


const hintedFoo = (function(Foo) {
  console.log(Foo.getFoo());
}).hint(IFoo); // Typehinting

hintedFoo(new A('success'));
hintedFoo(new B('fail'));
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что это про общих предков, а не про интерфейсы. Реализация интерфейса без реализации своего интерпретатора пока в голове не укладывается)